Using iterate to reclassify an image in Google Earth Engine
I'm currently working on transforming a raw DEM image into a reclassified image based on elevation ranges, assigning specific classes to certain elevation intervals. For instance, elevations between 0 and 500 meters are classified as class 1, 500 to 1000 meters as class 2, etc.
I've managed to achieve this using multiple .where() operations, but I'm looking for a more efficient method. I attempted to use .iterate() for this purpose, but I keep running into 'invalid argument types' errors, despite ensuring that argument types are correct and explicitly defined. Has anyone encountered this issue or does anyone have suggestions on how to effectively reclassify using .iterate() or another method in Google Earth Engine?
This is my original script:
var dataDem = ee.Image("USGS/GMTED2010_FULL")
  .select('med')
  .rename('elevation')
var dataDemClass = dataDem
  .where(dataDem.lte(500),1)
  .where(dataDem.gt(500).and(dataDem.lte(1000)),2)
  .where(dataDem.gt(1000).and(dataDem.lte(1500)),3)
  ...
  .where(dataDem.gt(8000),17)

And this is my attempt to use iterate, which has failed:
var elevClassesUpperBounds = ee.List.sequence(500,8000,500)
var elevClassesLowerBounds = ee.List.sequence(0,7500,500)
var dataDemClass2 = ee.List.sequence(0,15).iterate({
  function: function (index, demClassified) {
    var upperBound = ee.Number(elevClassesUpperBounds.get(index))
    var lowerBound = ee.Number(elevClassesLowerBounds.get(index))
    demClassified = ee.Image(demClassified)
    return demClassified
      .where(demClassified.gt(upperBound).and(demClassified.lte(lowerBound)),index)
  },
  first: ee.Image(dataDem),
})
print('dataDemClass2: ',dataDemClass2)


If your zones are evenly spaced, just use math.
// 0:499 -> 0, add 1.
var class = dataDem.divide(500).int().add(1)

If they're not linear, then make a list of upper ranges and use map to make a bunch of binary threshold images, and then just add them together.
var zones = ee.List([0, 100, 300, 900, 1700])
var classes = ee.ImageCollection(zones.map(function(n) {
    return dataDem.gt(ee.Image.constant(n))
})).reduce(ee.Reducer.sum())

